# How To Get Domain Name From IP?

Tags: vb.net, cmd, dns, domain-name

My question is How To Get Domain Name From Ip address Any ideas Will Be Accepted

I'm searching for that For 3 days no answer at all.

I want the program to work with unknown websites "I Create It Or The User Which he used It"

I give the IP address and the program will give me all the domain names For that server Like 216.58.211.100 >>>>> the result will bw >>>>>>www.google.com.

That it's so important to me right now. Why is it so difficult to do it? Any idea? I prefer VB.Net, but it's Ok with other languages or ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In theory, you should be able to call `Dns.GetHostEntry` and pass the IP address. I tried that passing "www.google.com" and got a particular IP address but when I tried again with that IP address I got a different host name and no aliases, so I'm not sure that there is a simple way using managed code. It may just be that that DNS server won't provide "www.google.com" as a host name, even though it recognises it.

Comment: Note that in my experience `Dns.GetHostEntry` is not always reliable.  Keep that in mind if you run into any odd issues where its not resolving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this. It's good for me.

```
Dim validip As Boolean
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim ipHost As IPHostEntry = New IPHostEntry()
    Application.DoEvents()

    Try
        ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(TextBox10.Text)
        validip = True
    Catch se As SocketException
        Dim message = se.Message.ToLower()

        If message.Equals("no such host is known") Then
            validip = False
        Else
            Throw
        End If
    End Try

    If validip Then

        For Each ip As IPAddress In ipHost.AddressList
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ip.AddressFamily.ToString())
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ip.ToString())
        Next

        ListBox1.Items.Add("Host name is : " & ipHost.HostName)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Could not resolve  unknown host.")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`nslookup` ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup))
or this script should help https://gist.github.com/jrothmanshore/2656003